# Creating new column by dividing one column by another freezes system

Tags: pandas

My system freezes and fans run very fast everytime I create a new Pandas column by dividing one column by another. I have also excluded rows containing 0 but it always freezes. The dataframe has 60077 rows and it works fine on smaller number of rows. System is i7 and 8GB

I am using the following code for new column:

```
df['C']  =  df['A'] / df['B']
```

Comment: Do you have `NaN` or mixed dtypes? What does `df.info()` return?

Comment: Column 1 dtype : Object  ; Values in Column 1 type : float      Column 2 dtype : float64 ; Values in Column 2 type : np.float64    @EdChum

Comment: Your dtypes are weird, how come you have python float, pandas float 64, and then numpy float 64? You'll need to post data, and code in order for others to try to reproduce your error.

Comment: what does `df.apply(lambda x: pd.isnull(x).any())` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there was a single-element list in one of the column which was messing with the whole process. It was created as a result of exception of a particular library. I took that list element as column value and everything worked out fine. Thanks a lot for your suggestion. It helped me find the error. @EdChum